# Why is Executor Compute Time so long when shuffle writing in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

For each Task, the Shuffle Write Time is just 2 seconds, but the Executor Compute Time can be ten minutes or more. The code is `reduceByKey`, there is no other operation in this stage. What does the system do during the Computation period? What can I do to reduce the time costs?

Comment: I have the same question. I am using PySpark, computing the same matrix multiplication of the same size is slower on each spark cores. Is this because the Spark map function acts like a for loop while in a single threaded python, the matrix operations are vectorized?